# how can put two xib in same view controller in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i am trying to make two xib for same view controller.i have some code for that but i dont know what will be the view name as per code.and is this code i have to put in view did load?

here is my code:

```
if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    NSLog(@"Ipad ");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Iphone %f ",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
        viewName=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"ViewControllerIphone5"];
         //this is iphone 5 xib
    } else {
        viewName=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"ViewController"];
         // this is iphone 4 xib
    }
}
```

please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: why you are not using the autolayout format, it support the all size screens

Comment: @Rahul Shrimali Better solution is use autolayout in this case no need to manage 2 xib.

Answer (score 1):

```
DetailView *detailView;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)//for iPad
    {
       detailView = [[DetailView alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailView_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    else //this is for iphone
    {
      CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (result.height==480)
    {
         detailView = [[DetailView alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailView_iPhone" bundle:nil];
         //this is iphone 4 xib
    }
    if (result.height==568)
    {
        detailView = [[DetailView alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailView_iPhone5" bundle:nil];
         // this is iphone 5 xib
    }

    }
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

Comment: i did by your method but my homeviewcontroller_iphone4.xib is not called.even in log it goes to that xib.

Comment: you add different xib for both iPhone4 and 5 if yes than can you iphone4 xib under same class in files owner??

Answer (score 0):

I have done this like

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size, CGSizeMake(640, 1136)))


UIViewController *homeViewController;
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        homeViewController = [[LGHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LGHomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        homeViewController            = [[LGHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LGHomeViewController_IPhone4" bundle:nil];
    }
```

Comment: 640,1136?are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I am :) its ratina so 568*2 = calculate your self :P

Comment: i put this code and debug through breakpoint and it go to iphone4 but as previously if i run application in 4inch its run perfect but in 3.5 all the images change their position and after implement your code no difference is found .i connect xib to my viewcontroller :(

Comment: Then is about your xib layout problem, are you using autolayout or spring-struts

Comment: yeah i m using autolayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
    #define IDIOM    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()
    #define IPAD     UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
    #define IPHONE   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.

           NSLog(@"Ipad ");

        }
        else
        {
            // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.

             YourViewController *yourVC;

            CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

            if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
            {
            yourVC = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController_iPhone5" bundle:nil];
            } 
           else 
           {
            yourVC= [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController_iPhone4" bundle:nil];

           }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the right NIB on init, not viewDidLoad. This should do it, but as others point out autolayout is the way to go generally.

```
- (id)init

    if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return [self initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerIpad" bundle:nil];
    }
    else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
    {
        return [self initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerIphone5" bundle:nil];
    } 
    else 
    {
        return [self initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: -(init) is not called

Comment: when you create your view controller simply call 'MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];' and the right NIB will get loaded.